Stability with the Variational Principle
In quantum mechanics you can use the variational principle to find an approximate bound to the energy of some state. My lecturer said that with this method the stability of an $H_2$ atom and a $H^+$ ion can be determined. This is where my confusion lies. How do you determine if the bond is stable or not. Does it have to do with finding that the energy is negative, which means it is a bound state, or what is it?

The energy will be negative because bonding is attractive. In fact, essentially all atoms will be attracted to one another to some degree, but a bond is an extremely stabilizing drop in energy.

IN my book they find an estimate energy of -12.86 eV for a H- ion, why is this then unstable, is it because it would have a higher energy than a H atom, leading to a state that is not bound?
